# Microsoft Excel - Pivot Table

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

In an Excel pivot table, 
I have September data with items A, B & C; the pivot table looks like below:

```
September Data      
A   20
B   30
C   40
```

However for October data I only have items B & C so the pivot looks like this:

```
October Data

B   500
C   60
```

How do I retain Item A in the pivot table even though it's not in October data?

```
A   (blank) 
B   500
C   60
```

This is just a simplified version of my problem. My monthly data is huge and I cannot append the data. I need to display the missing item A as I might have values for item A in other months. Besides that, I need to formularise it in a template so I need it to display item A.

Answer (score 1):

There's a setting in the PivotTable Field dialog called "Show items with no data." Select that.